How to prevent negative variance estimates in likelihood optimization?
I have this regression model in which 100 people have 20 measurements taken:
$$ y_{ij} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_{ij} + \beta_2 t_{ij} + u_i + \epsilon_{ij} $$
Where:

$ i = 1, 2, ..., 100 \text{ (patient index)} $

$ j = 1, 2, ..., 20 \text{ (measurement index)} $

$y_{ij}$ the outcome variable for patient $i$ at measurement $j$

$\beta_0$ is the intercept

$\beta_1$ is the coefficient for the time-invariant covariate $x_{ij}$

$\beta_2$ is the coefficient for the time variable $t_{ij}$

$u_i$ is the random effect for patient $i$,$ u_i \sim N(0, \sigma_u^2) $

$\epsilon_{ij}$ is the error term $ \epsilon_{ij} \sim N(0, \sigma_{\epsilon}^2) $


Crudely, we should be able to write the likelihood function for this model like this ( $ \beta = (\beta_0, \beta_1, \beta_2)^\top $):
$$
L(\beta, \sigma_u^2, \sigma_{\epsilon}^2) = \prod_{i=1}^{100} \left( (2\pi)^{-10} \det(\Sigma_i)^{-0.5} \exp\left( -\frac{1}{2} (\mathbf{y}_i - \mathbf{X}_i \beta)^\top \Sigma_i^{-1} (\mathbf{y}_i - \mathbf{X}_i \beta) \right) \right)
$$
I understand that one of the more common ways to estimate the parameters of this model is to use a combination of GLS (General Least Squares) and RMLE (Restricted Maximum Likelihood Estimation). This in theory should reduce the complexity of the optimization problem as we are effectively splitting it into two sub problems.
But I am just wondering: Suppose if we used the Fisher-Scoring method to try and estimate all parameters $ \theta = (\beta_0, \beta_1, \beta_2, \sigma_u^2, \sigma_{\epsilon}^2) $ at once:
$$
U(\theta) = \frac{\partial \log L(\theta)}{\partial \theta}
$$
$$\mathcal{I}_{\beta_j \beta_k}(\theta) = E \left[ \frac{\partial^2 \log L(\theta)}{\partial \beta_j \partial \beta_k} \right] $$
$$
\mathcal{I}(\theta) =
\begin{pmatrix}
\mathcal{I}_{\beta_0 \beta_0} & \mathcal{I}_{\beta_0 \beta_1} & \mathcal{I}_{\beta_0 \beta_2} & \mathcal{I}_{\beta_0 \sigma_u^2} & \mathcal{I}_{\beta_0 \sigma_{\epsilon}^2} \\
\mathcal{I}_{\beta_1 \beta_0} & \mathcal{I}_{\beta_1 \beta_1} & \mathcal{I}_{\beta_1 \beta_2} & \mathcal{I}_{\beta_1 \sigma_u^2} & \mathcal{I}_{\beta_1 \sigma_{\epsilon}^2} \\
\mathcal{I}_{\beta_2 \beta_0} & \mathcal{I}_{\beta_2 \beta_1} & \mathcal{I}_{\beta_2 \beta_2} & \mathcal{I}_{\beta_2 \sigma_u^2} & \mathcal{I}_{\beta_2 \sigma_{\epsilon}^2} \\
\mathcal{I}_{\sigma_u^2 \beta_0} & \mathcal{I}_{\sigma_u^2 \beta_1} & \mathcal{I}_{\sigma_u^2 \beta_2} & \mathcal{I}_{\sigma_u^2 \sigma_u^2} & \mathcal{I}_{\sigma_u^2 \sigma_{\epsilon}^2} \\
\mathcal{I}_{\sigma_{\epsilon}^2 \beta_0} & \mathcal{I}_{\sigma_{\epsilon}^2 \beta_1} & \mathcal{I}_{\sigma_{\epsilon}^2 \beta_2} & \mathcal{I}_{\sigma_{\epsilon}^2 \sigma_u^2} & \mathcal{I}_{\sigma_{\epsilon}^2 \sigma_{\epsilon}^2}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$$
\theta^{(k+1)} = \theta^{(k)} + \left( \mathcal{I}(\theta^{(k)}) \right)^{-1} U(\theta^{(k)})
$$
In this case, what is preventing the Fisher-Scoring method from returning negative variance estimates (i.e. $\sigma_{\epsilon}^2$ and $\sigma_u^2$)?  In practice, do we need some constraints to prevent the optimization algorithm from exploring negative regions of the parameter space?
E.g. Can we just impose a crude constraint in the optimization process via truncation?
sigma_u2 <- max(0, theta[1])  
sigma_e2 <- max(0, theta[2])  

Is this kind of truncation a standard practice?
(I know that there are more sophisticated methods to introduce constraints, e.g. using Lagrange Multipliers or reparametrizing the likelihood function all together such that these constraints are reflected .... but this will probably be very complicated ... working/differentiating/manipulating with the original likelihood is difficult enough ... so I was wondering if some naive form of truncation is statistically suitable)

Here are some algebraic manipulations ($J $is a matrix of all ones, and $I$ is the identity matrix).
First, I derived the Score Function:
$$ \log L_i = -\frac{1}{2}\left[ \log(\det(\mathbf{V})) + (\mathbf{y}_i - \mathbf{X}_i\boldsymbol{\beta})^\top \mathbf{V}^{-1} (\mathbf{y}_i - \mathbf{X}_i\boldsymbol{\beta}) \right] $$
$$ \begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial \log L_i}{\partial \boldsymbol{\beta}} &= \frac{\partial}{\partial \boldsymbol{\beta}} \left[ -\frac{1}{2} (\mathbf{y}_i - \mathbf{X}_i\boldsymbol{\beta})^\top \mathbf{V}^{-1} (\mathbf{y}_i - \mathbf{X}_i\boldsymbol{\beta}) \right] \\
&= \mathbf{X}_i^\top \mathbf{V}^{-1} (\mathbf{y}_i - \mathbf{X}_i\boldsymbol{\beta})
\end{aligned} $$
$$ \begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial \log L_i}{\partial \sigma_u^2} &= -\frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial}{\partial \sigma_u^2} \left[ \log(\det(\mathbf{V})) + (\mathbf{y}_i - \mathbf{X}_i\boldsymbol{\beta})^\top \mathbf{V}^{-1} (\mathbf{y}_i - \mathbf{X}_i\boldsymbol{\beta}) \right] \\
&= -\frac{1}{2} \left[ \text{tr}(\mathbf{V}^{-1} \mathbf{J}) - (\mathbf{y}_i - \mathbf{X}_i\boldsymbol{\beta})^\top \mathbf{V}^{-1} \mathbf{J} \mathbf{V}^{-1} (\mathbf{y}_i - \mathbf{X}_i\boldsymbol{\beta}) \right]
\end{aligned} $$
$$ \begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial \log L_i}{\partial \sigma_e^2} &= -\frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial}{\partial \sigma_e^2} \left[ \log(\det(\mathbf{V})) + (\mathbf{y}_i - \mathbf{X}_i\boldsymbol{\beta})^\top \mathbf{V}^{-1} (\mathbf{y}_i - \mathbf{X}_i\boldsymbol{\beta}) \right] \\
&= -\frac{1}{2} \left[ \text{tr}(\mathbf{V}^{-1} \mathbf{I}) - (\mathbf{y}_i - \mathbf{X}_i\boldsymbol{\beta})^\top \mathbf{V}^{-1} \mathbf{I} \mathbf{V}^{-1} (\mathbf{y}_i - \mathbf{X}_i\boldsymbol{\beta}) \right]
\end{aligned} $$
$$ \mathbf{S}(\boldsymbol{\beta}, \boldsymbol{\theta}) = \begin{pmatrix}
\mathbf{X}_i^\top \mathbf{V}^{-1} (\mathbf{y}_i - \mathbf{X}_i\boldsymbol{\beta}) \\
-\frac{1}{2} \left[ \text{tr}(\mathbf{V}^{-1} \mathbf{J}) - (\mathbf{y}_i - \mathbf{X}_i\boldsymbol{\beta})^\top \mathbf{V}^{-1} \mathbf{J} \mathbf{V}^{-1} (\mathbf{y}_i - \mathbf{X}_i\boldsymbol{\beta}) \right] \\
-\frac{1}{2} \left[ \text{tr}(\mathbf{V}^{-1} \mathbf{I}) - (\mathbf{y}_i - \mathbf{X}_i\boldsymbol{\beta})^\top \mathbf{V}^{-1} \mathbf{I} \mathbf{V}^{-1} (\mathbf{y}_i - \mathbf{X}_i\boldsymbol{\beta}) \right]
\end{pmatrix} $$
Next, the Fisher Information:
$$ \frac{\partial^2 \log L_i}{\partial \boldsymbol{\beta} \partial \boldsymbol{\beta}^\top} = -\mathbf{X}_i^\top \mathbf{V}^{-1} \mathbf{X}_i $$
$$ \frac{\partial^2 \log L_i}{\partial \sigma_u^2 \partial \sigma_e^2} = -\frac{1}{2} \text{tr}(\mathbf{V}^{-1} \mathbf{J} \mathbf{V}^{-1} \mathbf{I}) + \frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{y}_i - \mathbf{X}_i\boldsymbol{\beta})^\top \mathbf{V}^{-1} \mathbf{J} \mathbf{V}^{-1} \mathbf{I} \mathbf{V}^{-1} (\mathbf{y}_i - \mathbf{X}_i\boldsymbol{\beta}) $$
$$ \frac{\partial^2 \log L_i}{\partial \boldsymbol{\beta} \partial \sigma_u^2} = \mathbf{X}_i^\top \mathbf{V}^{-1} \mathbf{J} \mathbf{V}^{-1} (\mathbf{y}_i - \mathbf{X}_i\boldsymbol{\beta}) $$
$$ \frac{\partial^2 \log L_i}{\partial \boldsymbol{\beta} \partial \sigma_e^2} = \mathbf{X}_i^\top \mathbf{V}^{-1} \mathbf{I} \mathbf{V}^{-1} (\mathbf{y}_i - \mathbf{X}_i\boldsymbol{\beta}) $$
Here is the Fisher Information (The expected value of $Y - x \beta$ is 0. When we substitute this into the derivatives, some of the terms in the matrix become $0$):
$$ \mathcal{I}(\boldsymbol{\beta}, \boldsymbol{\theta}) = \begin{pmatrix}
(\mathbf{X}_i^\top \mathbf{V}^{-1} \mathbf{X}_i)_{11} & (\mathbf{X}_i^\top \mathbf{V}^{-1} \mathbf{X}_i)_{12} & 0 & 0 \\
(\mathbf{X}_i^\top \mathbf{V}^{-1} \mathbf{X}_i)_{21} & (\mathbf{X}_i^\top \mathbf{V}^{-1} \mathbf{X}_i)_{22} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2}\text{tr}(\mathbf{V}^{-1} \mathbf{J} \mathbf{V}^{-1} \mathbf{J}) & \frac{1}{2}\text{tr}(\mathbf{V}^{-1} \mathbf{J} \mathbf{V}^{-1} \mathbf{I}) \\
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2}\text{tr}(\mathbf{V}^{-1} \mathbf{J} \mathbf{V}^{-1} \mathbf{I}) & \frac{1}{2}\text{tr}(\mathbf{V}^{-1} \mathbf{I} \mathbf{V}^{-1} \mathbf{I})
\end{pmatrix} $$


Yes, in general we have to be careful about this.

we could set constraints for each parameter (these are often called box constraints because setting independent inequality constraints on a set of parameters confines the solutions to a "rectangular hypervolume" (== a box)). You can't necessarily do this by a crude truncation of a Fisher scoring step — see e.g. this Computational Science SE question or the L-BFGS-B quasi-Newton method ...
we could estimate parameters on the scale of $\sigma$ rather than $\sigma^2$, in which case we can't get negative variance estimates — but we would usually want to set the constraints anyway, for identifiability (i.e., for any constant $C$, $\sigma=C$ and $\sigma=-C$ will give identical likelihoods, because the likelihood function only uses $\sigma^2$)
we could estimate the parameters on the scale of $\log(\sigma)$. This is more convenient than doing constrained optimization, and works well when the estimated parameters are not on or near the boundary. When they are on our near the boundary (in particular singular fits when the best estimate of $\sigma_u^2$ is 0), we have problems because the likelihood surface gets flat as we go to $\sigma=0$ or $\log(\sigma) \to -\infty$ ... if you have derivatives (or second derivatives) with respect to $\sigma^2$, you can get derivatives with respect to $\log(\sigma^2)$ by the chain rule ...



can you explain why there would be an identifiability problem in "estimating sigma instead of sigma^2"?



the idea about log-scale. Is this an easy fix? Do I just add log(variance) in the computer function and proceed? or do i need to re-derive all the derivatives with log variance terms?



do you think my initial idea of "max(0, theta[1]) " is a valid approach? in a way, is this like creating a box constraint?


Edited my answer to address these questions.

@user430997 The problem with max(0, theta[1]) is that the derivative wrt theta[1] is now zero for negative theta[1] and is discontinuous at zero. Either could be a problem for an optimiser

thanks Ben ... Can I post the code I wrote that performs this optimization process?

I posted the equations and the code ... I will try to re-do this tomorrow with the logarithm strategy ...

Hi Dr. Bolker, I just read that you are one of the authors of the lme4 package? I was just wondering - how is lme4 able to perform derivatives of matrix objects with random variables? is it using symbolic differentiation?

While gradients are available for some special cases of mixed models (I think Doug Bates's MixedModels.jl package for Julia uses them), lme4 uses only gradient-free optimizers (e.g. Powell's BOBYQA). (For LMMs the optimization only needs to be done over the variance-covariance parameters, the fixed effect coefficients can be profiled out.) See vignette("lmer", package = "lme4") for full computational details.
